# Volume by rotating $y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus

Consider the curve  $y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, for $x \ge 0$. The volume formed by rotating the curve about the y axis is to be calculated.

---

The formula to calculate the rotational volume of a function $f$ about the $x$-axis is $$V=\pi\int_a^b f^2(x)dx.$$

My solution consists of finding the inverse function ($x^2=\frac1y-1$) and then using the formula above.

The resulting integral 
$$V=\lim_{a\to0}\ \pi\int_a^1 x^2dy=\lim_{a\to0}\ \pi\left[  \ln y-y\right]_a^1$$ 
cannot be calculated, although I know there must exist a solution since the total area under the original curve is 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac \pi 2.$$

Could someone point out my mistake?

Comment: Who told you that the volume must be finite because the area happens to be finite?

Comment: Just like Mickep stated, finite area does not implies finite volume. Just like the length of the curve of $\frac1{1+x^2}$ is infinite but the area is finite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's truncate the infinite volume at some positive height $0<a<1$ above the $x$-axis, ignoring the infinite part on the right, and calculate the volume of this part only. As you pointed out, the result should be

$$\pi\int_a^1\left(\frac{1}{y}-1\right)dy=\pi(a-\ln a - 1)$$

Letting $a$ tend to zero, you see that the infinite figure has infinite volume.